# StreamBuilder is not able to re-route even though condition is true

Tags: flutter

I am building Flutter authentication app using firebase. Upon successful login, StreamBuilder gets new data but not redirecting to desired component, instead it stays on login page. Here is the code snippet:

```
StreamBuilder<UserModel>(
          stream: _authService.user,
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return DashboardScreen(snapshot.data);
            }
            return HomeScreen();
            // return snapshot.hasData
            //     ? DashboardScreen(snapshot.data)
            //     : HomeScreen();
          },
        )
```

The only thing You should know that from HomeScreen user can choose Login or Register option. That will open up new screen(AuthScreen) and on that screen I've Login/Register form. after successful login/Register, it stays on the same page even though snapshot.hasData is true. Is that an issue? Is flutter not able to figure out previous route? I really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Note: If I replace HomeScreen() with AuthScreen(), it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine routes as a deck of cards, if you route to another screen, that's a new card on top of your current cards.

The `StreamBuilder` is probably updating just fine, you can check this by refreshing the Flutter Inspector widget tree, seeing there the `DashboardScreen`. But you won't see it on the screen because the route is on top of it.

After a successful login pop your route and see if works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Michel. Thats what I was thinking and I'm using Navigator.pop(context) after successful login. It is working as expected now but I am little bit concerned as I don't know if this is optimum solution. I am accepting this answer though.